# Uint8Array based Image: Fastest way to copy sub image

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I have an RGBA image represented as an Uint8Array and I want to copy a sub rectangle of that image into a new array in the fastest possible way.

Currently I do something like this:

```
let sourceImage = { width: 640, height: 400, data: new Uint8Array( 640 * 480 * 4 ) };
let destImage = { width: 100, height: 100, data: new Uint8Array( 100 * 100 * 4 ) };
let offX = 100, offY = 50;

for( y=0; y < destImage.height; ++y )
{
  let toCopyArray = sourceImage.data.subarray( (offY+y) * sourceImage.width * 4 + offX * 4, (offY+y) * sourceImage.width * 4 + offX * 4 + image.width * 4 );
  destImage.data.set( toCopyArray, y * destImage.width * 4 );
}
```

Is there a faster way ?

Comment: It should be fast; you can gain a little by precalculating some of the static values (f.ex `let sWidth = sourceImage.width<<2;` etc. outside the loop). You can also unwind the loop, say, if you know the height is dividable by 2 or 4 you can copy the inner operations 2 or 4 times in a single iteration.

Comment: Of course, using canvas and drawImage on it will gain juice from the GPU if available, but get penalty from getImageData. If the latter is necessary or if you can use drawImage is of course dependent on your scenario, but something to consider for the design.

Comment: I will try out if drawImage / getImageData are faster, it may help with large images. Just not sure how much of an impact getImageData will have as it returns an Uint8ClampedArray which needs to be converted, but at least it can be converted in one go. Thanks.